# Only one of my many notifications are starting an Activity outside of my Application

Tags: android

I am able to generate and display multiple notifications, all starting the same activity but displaying different information depending on the extra that is attached to the intent that starts up the Activity.  When I am within my application, all the notifications are able to start the Activity, but when I am outside of the application, only one is able to start the Activity (the first that I click on), the rest do nothing once clicked on (except disappear).  This is my code for generating the notifications. The "reqCode" represents unique numbers.

```
        Resources r = getResources();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplaySearchTickerAlert_Activity.class);
        i.putExtra(NewArticleNotification_Service.QUERY_TICKER, searchQuery);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, reqCode, i, 0);


        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setTicker(r.getString(R.string.ticker_alert))
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call)
                .setContentTitle(r.getString(R.string.ticker_alert))
                .setContentText("Newly published for search term: " + "\""
                        + searchQuery + "\"").setContentIntent(pi).setAutoCancel(true).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(reqCode, notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your activity is already being displayed. Only the first notification will bring it to the foreground. The rest of notifications will dispatch a new intent that depending on your activity [`android:launchMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) you might be able to catch on the [`onNewIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) callback.

Comment: so why is that the notifications all work properly and launch the same Activity (with different content) when I am inside my application but not when I am outside?  My launch mode for this Activity is "standard". So what is the solution?